# How to make algorithm which replace elements in array with help array with indexes using c?

Tags: arrays, c, function, replace

I have two arrays:

```
int mainArr[10] = {111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999, 3000};
int indexArray[10] = {6, 2, 9, 0, 1, 3, 7, 4, 5, 8};
```

And it must work like this: `indexArray` replace elements in `mainArr`. The sixth element replaces the zero element, the second element replaces the first element etc.

At the end it should be like this:

```
777 333 3000 111 222 444 888 555 666 999 - mainArr
^    ^    ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^
6    2    9   0   1   3   7   4   5   8 - indexArray
```

I have a piece of my code for to understand what is happening:

```
int replaceByIndex (int startArray[], int customIndexes[]);

int main ()
{
    int *result;
    int mainArr[10] = {111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999, 3000};
    int indexArray[10] = {6, 2, 9, 0, 1, 3, 7, 4, 5, 8};
    result = replaceByIndex(mainArr, indexArray);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", result[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

int replaceByIndex (int startArray[], int customIndexes[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        startArray[i] = customIndexes[i];
    }
    return startArray;
}
```

I just made an algorithm that replaces the element of an array, but that's not what I need.

Comment: Does it have to be in-place? Otherwise it is easy to put the result in a new array.

Comment: for simplicity, it's better to create a new array

Comment: Then it's easy. Something like `for ( i=0; i < 10; i++) destArray[i] = srcArray[indexArray[i]];`

Comment: it works but unknown numbers are output, only first number is true. Like that:

777
4199120
4199120
3514368
8
6422140
888
6422476
2003094720
-1899839143

Comment: This is another problem arising from some incorrect usage of arrays. You might want to ask another question if you don't figure it out.

Comment: Everything works, I solved all the problems. Thank you! Have a nice day =)

Comment: @EugeneSh. in place is much more chalenging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int *replaceByIndex(int *startArray, int startArray_size,
                    int *customIndex, int customIndex_size) {
    int *tmp = malloc(sizeof(int) * startArray_size);
    for (int i = 0; i < customIndex_size; ++i) {
        tmp[i] = startArray[customIndex[i]];
    }
    return tmp; // must be freed after use
}
```

this is the simplest way to archive what you want. The problem with your desire solution is that the custom index is a reference to the old position in the array not the new one you are building so you either format the customIndex array in an other way or you create a new array.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *replaceByIndex(int startArray[], int customIndexes[], int destinationarray[])
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    destinationarray[i] = startArray[customIndexes[i]];

  return destinationarray;
}

int main()
{
  int* result;
  int mainArr[10] = { 111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999, 3000 };
  int indexArray[10] = { 6, 2, 9, 0, 1, 3, 7, 4, 5, 8 };
  int newarray[10]; // will contain the array with swapped values

  result = replaceByIndex(mainArr, indexArray, newarray);

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", result[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

There is still room for improvements. For example:

- Easy: the array size is hardcoded as `10` in `replaceByIndex`, you should replace this by a parameter.
- Easy: maybe you should check that none of the indexes in `customIndexes` exceeds the array size.
- Not so easy: you could do the replacement in place without a 3rd array

I leave these as exercises to you.

Comment: `ou could do the replacement in place without a 3rd array` you did the easy part :) sow us this more complicated

Comment: @0___________ we don't want to do _all_ of the OP's work, do we? 

Comment: You did the trivial part. Try not the trivial one

Comment: @0___________ feel free to do it yourself. You'll get my upvote.